# Peewee intersection of queries - is it the only way?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, peewee

I am using "peewee" module as a Sqlite3 DB ORM & I just wanted to ask if this is a valid (good?) code. I have tables "Device", "Location" and "DeviceLocation" (dealing with many-to-many relationships). A device can be in more locations at the same time and in a location can be placed many devices.

I need to find out which devices are in more locations at the same time. At first I wanted to do it in a single query but I didn't find a way to do it, so now I am asking if this is the right approach...

This code works and in this example I am asking to get devices which are in "home" location and "kitchen" location at the same time. So is this the only way to do it?

```py
import peewee

# Models

class Location(BaseModel):
  name = CharField(unique=False, null=False)

class Device(BaseModel):
  mac = CharField(unique=True, null=False)
  label = CharField(unique=False, null=True)

class DeviceLocation(BaseModel):
  device = ForeignKeyField(Device, backref='location')
  location = ForeignKeyField(Location, backref='device')

# Fill the DB ...

# Queries

q0 = (DeviceLocation
        .select(Device.label)
        .join(Device)
        .switch(DeviceLocation)
        .join(Location)
      )

q1 = q0.where((Location.name == "home"))
q2 = q0.where((Location.name == "kitchen"))

q = q1.intersect(q2)
print("Devices in 'home' and 'kitchen' locations at the same time:")
for x in q:
  print(f"{x.device.label}")
```

EDIT:
This solution does only work when selecting only single model like "Device".